# Price plan, feedback on database design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

This is a example Price Plan (See image).

[image]

Matrix £15 and Matrix £20 is a contract plan for mobile phone. Every plan has different point for each phone.

This is what I came up with database design tables. Is this correct?

## Phones

- phone_id (P)
- name

4, iPhone

9, Blackberry

## phone_plan

- phoneplan_id (P)
- phone_id (F)
- package_id (F)

1, 4, 6

2, 4, 7

3, 9, 6

4, 9, 7

## plan_packag

- package_id (P)
- plan_name
- monthly_cost

6, Matrix, 15.00

7, Matrix, 20.00

## points

- point_id (P)
- phone_id (F)
- package_id (F)
- point

1, 4, 6, 6.0

2, 4, 7, 6.6

3, 9, 6, 8.3

4, 9, 7, 9.2

Comment: What are you trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: The answer to your question is Yes. The answer to your question is No. The answer to your question is Depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need to query on the points independent of the phone or plan, I would suggest you to merge the `Points` table to merge with the `Phone Plan` table and make it `PhonePlanPoint` Table as below

**PhonePlanPoint**

```
    phoneplan_id (P)
    phone_id (F)
    package_id (F)
    point
```

Comment: Thank you. What the data type should be for storing points? (eg: 6.0, 10.5, 20.5, etc)